# Исправить ошибку в запросе для PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
        id SERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        username TEXT NOT NULL,
        login TEXT NOT NULL,
        password TEXT NOT NULL,
        email TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        create_date Timestamp,
        access CHARACTER(10) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY (id),
        CONSTRAINT user_unique UNIQUE (login, password)
);
```

И есть запрос который должен редактировать пользователя, и если `CONSTRAINT user_unique UNIQUE (login, password)` нарушено и редактирования не произошло вернуть `false`, в случае удачи `true`.

```
with ins as (
  UPDATE test
  SET  username = 'new_username', login = 'new_login', password = 'new_password', email = 'new_email', access = 'admin'
  WHERE id = 6
  on conflict on constraint user_unique do nothing
  returning id
)
```

Однако этот запрос падает с ошибкой

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "on"
LINE 5:   on conflict on constraint user_unique do nothing
```

Помогите пожалуйста это исправить. Спасибо.

У меня есть аналогичный запрос для добавления пользователя, который работает без проблем, может быть это чем-то поможет:

```
with ins as (
  INSERT INTO test (id, username, login, password, email, create_date, access)
  VALUES (DEFAULT, 'asd', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd', now()::timestamp, 'asd')
  on conflict on constraint user_unique do nothing
  returning id
)
```

Поясните пожалуйста в чем разница между первым приведенным запросом и этим.

Comment: Потому что нет `on conflict` в команде `update`.  https://postgrespro.ru/docs/ команды sql в частности https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/sql-commands.html

Comment: А зачем вам такой странный констраинт. почему вы позволяете двум пользователям быть с одним логином но разными паролями. Это огромная дыра в безопасности. Новый пользователь указав такой же логин и случайно выбрав такой же пароль узнает, что уже есть пользователь с таким же паролем и следовательно может под ним входить. Учитывая любовь пользователей к паролям 123456 и qwerty проблема более чем актуальна

Comment: @Mike вообще-то да если слишком простой пароль то не очень получается. Спасибо за подсказку.